# Select a column of data to the end and only one row to the right

Tags: excel, vba

I could find how you select data to the end of the column and to however right it goes, but I only want it to select one row to the right. In my data I have two columns with the same amount of entries so there should be no problem selecting.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for such simple/dumb questions I dont usually code. thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you use Macro Recorder to record it. Excel will write the code for you. It writes poor code but it works.

Comment: `Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Select`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RangeFromStart()
    '3 ways to select both rows
    
    Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Select
    
    Range(Range("D1"), Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Select
    
    Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown)).Resize(, 2).Select
    
End Sub
```

[image]